# Ayuda con botones de Javascript confirm

Tags: php, javascript

> Hola, uso javascript en el boton cancelar uso un confirm si el usuario acepta sale y recarga la pagina, pero si cancela debe cerrar el confirm y seguir en el modal de atras. Como hago eso?. Ahora mismo al hacer clic en cancelar del cuadro de dialogo, me recarga la pagina y se sale del modal. Me podrian ayudar por favor.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    $('#cancelar').on('click', function(){
    var parametros = {
        'xcodigo' : $('#p0').val(),
        'xcliente' : $('#p3').val()
     };
     if (confirm('Desea Cancelar?')){
    $.ajax({  //envia POST a otro php
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'pedido.cancel.php',
        data: parametros,
        success: function(data){
            var url = document.URL;
            location.href = url;
            }           
        });
    }
});
```

> Asi tengo el codigo en el js en cancelar

Answer (score 3):

El problema es que al dar clic en el botón no solo tu evento esta escuchando el clic, sino también el del modal y se cierra de todas maneras.

Solución:
Remplaza el botón por otro que no tenga los data de cerrar y haz lo siguiente (cancelar2 seria el ID de tu nuevo botón)

```
 $('#cancelar2').on('click', function(evt){
    var parametros = {
        'xcodigo' : $('#p0').val(),
        'xcliente' : $('#p3').val()
     };
     if (confirm('Desea Cancelar?')){
        $.ajax({  //envia POST a otro php
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'pedido.cancel.php',
            data: parametros,
            success: function(data){
                var url = document.URL;
                location.href = url;
                }           
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, ya lo solucione ,en el input de cancelar tenia este codigo data-dismiss="modal" y ese lo que hacia era cerrar el modal tambien , al cancelar en el confirm. Muchas gracias...

Comment: Genial, no conocía ese data-dismiss. Tu solución es mas limpia, Saludos!